# C#: System.Windows.Controls.UserControl as Listbox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm a Java developer whose inherited a web project from another team whose sole developer upped and quit. The majority of the project is written in Spring, JSPs and jQuery, however there is one component that is a Silverlight XAP.

Of course, the project was just handed to me and we're already having production issues with it. I've never written a lick of C# before, and am scrambling to try and fix this as fast as humanly possible.

This is a Microsoft VS 2010 (Pro Edition) C# solution project, with a presentation layer consisting of XAML and CS files. The component that needs to be fixed is a file uploader that allows users to choose 1+ files from their machine and place them in a "queue" (a listbox). Then, with the click of a single button, all the "queued" files get uploaded to our server.

I need to be able to tell when the listbox is empty (when there are 0 files queued/populating it). This feature is represented in the code by a XAML/CS pair of files named `ListItemControl.xaml` and `ListItemControl.xaml.cs` respectively.

Here is the beginning of the CS file:

```
namespace silv.Uploader
{
    public partial class ListItemControl : UserControl
    {
        private UserFile UserFile { get { return (UserFile)this.DataContext; } }

        public ListItemControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ...
```

Applying Java concepts to its C# cousin (as I've been told), this looks like my `ListItemControl` is an in-house class extending a Microsoft built-in type of `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`. Furthermore, that it has a `UserFile` property (which I assume is another homegrown type) representing a file or set of files that needs to be uploaded.

So first, as a sanity check: **can someone please confirm those assumptions above?!?**

First off, in Java/Swing-land, you would instantiate or subclass a `JList` (listbox) type, which has built-in methods/models to determine the number of items populating it at any given time.

**What is the ListItemControl/UserControl equivalent in C#-land?**

In this CS file I don't see any methods for determining size/length/counts of data. Same when I F12 (Go to Definition) `UserControl`.

Essentially, I'm asking here: how do I query this listbox component for the number of items it is populated with? Thanks in advance for any nudges in the right direction...

**Edit**: Below is a snippet of the XAML that I *believe* is responsible for initializing this listbox:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="svFiles" IsEnabled="True"     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,1,18,252">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stkMain" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl  x:Name="icFiles" KeyUp="ScrollViewer_KeyUp" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListItemControl ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Your assumptions seem correct, but we're missing some data here, specifically the contents of the XAML file. Most of the instantiation goes on there. I'm guessing that we'll see a <ListBox> control declaration, with a datatemplate that specifies that each item will be represented by a ListItemControl. This ListBox is what you're after. The ListItemControl is just one entry in the ListBox, so naturally you won't be able to get the length of data from it.

Comment: Ahhhh - give me a few minutes and I'll grab a XAML snippet. I was under the impression that the control referred to the listbox as a whole.

Comment: Is that snippet what I was omitting, or am I looking in the wrong place still?  Its the only reference to the string "list" I can find anywhere in the XAML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated snippet seems to be the right piece of XAML - you have the `ItemsControl`, which is a generic repeater control for rendering a collection of items. What I still don't see is where the items are added, but that might be somewhere else in the code.

However, since the `ItemsControl` is given a name, so you can access that:

```
ItemCollection items = icFiles.Items;
int count = items.Count;
```

Where exactly are you trying to access the queue length? This needs to be in the code-behind of the window that the `ItemsControl` is defined in.

Comment: Yes - this file is `FileUploader.xaml` and I need to make changes to `FileUploader.xaml.cs`. Thanks for all your help @Avner - I know this is a simple question but getting called into work at 4:00 AM to fix a production issue in a language you've never coded before...it's frustrating. Thanks again!

Comment: Best way to learn, right? What, no? No, no it isn't. I feel your pain. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally a `List<Something>` control would implement or inherit from a control which implements the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface.

You don't provide the full mark-up but I expect there's more code below which exposes some property such as `.Length` or `.Items.Count` which would tell you the number of elements in the array, dictionary, etc.

I'm being necessarily general here, as the precise property names will depend on how it implemented in the code we can't see.

Comment: Thanks @Widor - I'll grab the necessary XAML and edit my original question.